# Typing in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have function with a parameter named param like this:

```
function x(param: One | Two) {
    //do something
}

interface One {
    value: IValue,
    name: string,
    id: number
}
interface Two {
    value: IValue2,
    name: string,
    id: number,
    selected: boolean
}
```

Can I use for same parameter , two different interfaces? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can, and you have the parameter syntax correct! For reference, TypeScript refers to this as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

The main caveat to using them is that you can only access the common members across all the types - for example, both your interfaces contain `name`, `value` and `id`, so you would be able to use these in your function. However, only `interfaceTwo` has the `selected` member, so that wouldn't be available.

As an aside, I don't know if the example is something you just typed up on the fly, so you may well already know this, but your interfaces are not defined correctly - you need to use the `interface` keyword and end the lines with semicolons. It's also a convention to give types `TitleCase` names:

```
function x(param: InterfaceOne | InterfaceTwo){
    console.log(param.name);     // Valid!
    console.log(param.id);       // Valid!

    console.log(param.value);    // Valid - but has the type IValue | IValue2,
                                 // so you can only access the common fields
                                 // of those types!

    console.log(param.selected); // INVALID - InterfaceOne doesn't have a selected member
}

interface InterfaceOne {
    value: IValue;
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

interface InterfaceTwo {
    value: IValue2;
    name: string;
    id: number;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

Comment: if at some point you would want to use param.selected property, you can define and use a type-guard function: function isInterfaceTwo(param) : param is InterfaceTwo { ... } . more on that [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6/)

Comment: @baryo: Yeah, I didn't really feel qualified to go into detail on type guards cause I've never used them, but they definitely sound like they could be helpful in this kind of situation!